# Getting driving distance and inserting into sql server 2008

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with lat/long for two points and I need to automatically insert driving distance (not point to point).  I know I have to use a 3rd party and I would prefer to do everything in T-SQL - if possible.

I have been working with Google and managed to get the distance in 2 ways (not in SQL):

1) Javascript: This doesnt seem like a viable solution but I found some code online that produces the distance but the address has to be manually entered and I still don't know how to get that number into my table.  Is there a way to run JavaScript in SQL and use my lat/long columns as parameters?  My guess is no, but I figured I would ask anyway.  If there is a way than I can post the code so you can show me how.

2) Found this and it seems like it could work: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin={PlaceA}&destination={PlaceB}&sensor=false

which returns results in XML.  However, there are multiple distance nodes that arent uniquely identified.  Also, is there a way to run this in SQL and use my lat/long columns as parameters for the origin and destination fields, then enter the LAST

```
    <distance>
      <value>Number</value>
        <text>Number</text>
    </distance>
```

that is returned into my table?

If there is any way to do this through SQL than I am open to any method that works.

The two methods I posted don't really help me get the info into my table and I dont know how to run them from SQL server.

Comment: What are you doing this for?  There should be some sort of commercial package (Especially for SQL Server) that can do address validation/driving distance - this will typically come with come guarantee of accuracy.  Otherwise, just about all RDBMSs will allow you to write custom procedures that can do just about anything, including making calls to external web services (rather dangerous, though).  What's wrong with having your app server call the external service, and insert it at that point (along with any other data, like additional points).

Comment: What we are trying to do is look at employees home address and measure the distance to their work location and if that distance is over a certain mileage than it will kick off an email with options (all this data is stored on sql server).  I have their lat/long for their home and work locations but figuring out the driving distance is the part that is throwing me.  Also, the driving distance is the only data I need.  The unfortunate part is that I have $0 to work with so it has to be a solution that uses our existing resources.

Comment: The route returned by Google/whatever may not be the route that person uses to travel - for any number of reasons.  Will you use the fastest, shortest, most scenic, or some other route?  What happens if the employee is using public transportation (which often takes slight detours, essentially), so they may be eligible for one of your options, but the driving distance you calculate is too short to kick off the email?  Most web services apply some sort of daily limit for non-paying customers (and certain uses are against the TOS, officially); are you likely to hit any limits?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  We aren't concerned with the route they actually take or how they choose to travel.  The distance is needed to make recommendations to their supervisor for possible alternate work locations.  I believe Google has a 2500 daily limit and if I reach it than I will stagger how often the email is sent or change another metric to bring my limit back in line with Google's T&C.

Comment: Based simply off driving distance?  No seriously, I'd probably get the top few options just from point-to-point distance, and hand it off; Strict driving distance won't cover certain problems with routes: hills (maybe they bike to work), tolls, parking problems, traffic patterns, additional forms of transportation (ie ferry across lake instead of around it), etc.  If you're seriously going to be approaching a 2500 limit, the locals will usually know better than a corporate office.

Comment: They were very clear that they did not want point to point (that would have made this very easy).  I was just looking to see if I was on the right track with the XML or if there was some other way to make it happen.  If I am on the right path do you know how to make it work?